# How can I make a private (i.e. not hosted on GitHub) brew tap?

Tags: homebrew

I would like to have a private `brew tap` for homebrew that is not hosted on GitHub. I've tried simply cloning the tap's repo into `/usr/local/Library/Taps` but doesn't appear to work. Anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *new* short answer is **yes**: `brew any-tap` [has been merged](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/40326) into `brew tap` so any repository, including private GitHub ones should now be supported.

> `brew tap` restricts users to GitHub and checks for private repos. I created
>   `brew any-tap` to support a wider variety of taps.
>
> With very small changes (and no extra flags!), this PR brings `any-tap` to brew.
>
> Users can use brew tap with GitHub as they always have or add one extra 
>   argument and tap any repository of any type from anywhere.
>
> tl;dr
>
> `brew tap user/name              # Same as it ever was`
>   `brew tap user/name URL          # Tap URL, whatever it happens to be`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's not supported, but there's a hacky way to do it if you're bound and determined: https://github.com/telemachus/homebrew-anytap

Comment: I'm flattered to see this here, but I hope it's not too hacky. ;) More seriously, I've been using it over a year. Other than one hiccup when Homebrew changed their API, it's been smooth sailing.

Comment: I'm not dissing. I'm just saying that it's not part of "Homebrew proper" and they clearly don't care about breaking it, etc. (the aforementioned hiccup.) I've also been using this for almost a month now, and everything's been mostly fine.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really take it as a diss. In fact, I was grinning for hours after I ran into this. It's not often that I run into my own stuff this way. It's a great thrill.

Comment: Looks like the ability to tap private repos has been pulled in homebrew itself: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/40326

Comment: Yay! It's about time! Thanks for the heads up.